# HIve: Data format changing while converting from ORC to TEXT

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, create-table

I have a hive table with the following schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_test.user_arry(
  cstid string, 
  prdctsslctd array<string>, 
  indvprc array<bigint>, 
  dscntamt array<bigint>, 
  prdctsrjctd array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
   '/location/on/a/hadoop/'
```

Data present in it, is in below format:

```
--------------------------------------------------------  
 name | prdctsslctd | indvprc | dscntamt | prdctsrjctd 
--------------------------------------------------------   
 cctg65  ["m_jns","cbyht"]        ["23","6"]       ["1","1"] ["shs","jkt"]
 jju89o0 ["top","jeans_wmn"]      ["55","45"]      [NULL]         [NULL]
 ju34hd  ["laychps","candy","toy"]["3","5","67"]["12","8"]["candy"]
```

Trying to pull this data into a table having the data type as `string` for all the columns

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_test.user_strng(
  cstid string, 
  prdctsslctd string, 
  indvprc string, 
  dscntamt string, 
  prdctsrjctd string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS textfile
LOCATION
 '/location/on/a/hadoop/';
```

Using:

```
insert into db_test.user_strng select * from db_test.user_arry;
```

Actual O/P:

```
--------------------------------------------------------  
 name | prdctsslctd | indvprc | dscntamt | prdctsrjctd 
--------------------------------------------------------   
 cctg65  m_jnscbyht        236       11     shsjkt
 jju89o0 topjeans_wmn      5545      NULL   NULL
 ju34hd  laychpscandytoy   3567      128    candy
```

Expected O/P:

```
--------------------------------------------------------  
 name | prdctsslctd | indvprc | dscntamt | prdctsrjctd 
--------------------------------------------------------   
 cctg65  "m_jns","cbyht"          "23","6"         "1","1"   "shs","jkt"
 jju89o0 "top","jeans_wmn"        "55","45"         NULL           NULL
 ju34hd  "laychps","candy","toy"  "3","5","67"     "12","8"  "candy"
```

Not getting where the things are going wrong Or, missing out on something?

```
Update_1
```

O/P from the table after performing the conversion array to array:

```
ALTER TABLE user_arry CHANGE indvprc indvprc array<string>;
ALTER TABLE user_arry CHANGE dscntamt dscntamt array<string>;


--------------------------------------------------------  
 name | prdctsslctd | indvprc | dscntamt | prdctsrjctd 
--------------------------------------------------------   
 cctg65  ["m_jns","cbyht"]        ["23","6"]       ["1","1"] ["shs","jkt"]
 jju89o0 ["top","jeans_wmn"]      ["55","45"]      []         []
 ju34hd  ["laychps","candy","toy"]["3","5","67"]["12","8"]["candy"]
```

Final O/P from the table where all datatypes are string:

```
--------------------------------------------------------  
 name | prdctsslctd | indvprc | dscntamt | prdctsrjctd 
--------------------------------------------------------   
 cctg65  m_jns    cbyht      23   6    1      1      shs  jkt
 jju89o0 top      jeans_wmn  55   45       
 ju34hd  laychps  candy      toy  3    5      67     12    8    candy
```

Still not getting the desired o/p.

```
Update_2
```

As suggested, did the change for `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` . Getting the data in desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all arrays type to `array <string>`:

```
alter table ALTER TABLE user_arry CHANGE indvprc indvprc array<string>;
alter table ALTER TABLE user_arry CHANGE dscntamt dscntamt array<string>;
```

And according to your data example, `array<bigint>` is not proper format for values like `"23.45"`.  `array<string>` should work fine for your data file.

Use `concat_ws` to convert arrays to comma-delimited strings:

```
insert into db_test.user_strng 
select  name, 
        concat_ws(',',prdctsslctd)  as prdctsslctd,
        concat_ws(',',indvprc)      as indvprc,
        concat_ws(',',dscntamt)     as dscntamt,
        concat_ws(',',prdctsrjctd) as prdctsrjctd 
  from db_test.user_arry;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working, but all the fields are now coming under different columns i.e. One value-one column. I've updated the question with the o/p. Would you mind to have a look at it??

Comment: @rocking what is the output from arry table after ALTER?

Comment: Have updated my question with the requested details.

Comment: @rocking Did you insert into table with string from table  array<string>  using concat_ws ? right? Then probably the problem is because FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   - usually Hive uses TAB. The thing is that you concatenated arrays with comma and FIELDS TERMINATED is also comma, this is why it thinks it is different columns and shift values. Use TAB ('\t') for FIELDS TERMINATED